# Dropping inline divs to a new line

Tags: html, css

Sorry, I'm sure this question has been asked before, but if there anyway to do the following:

I have three divs in-line like the diagram shown below, when the browser window is shrunk it automatically drops each div to the next line. I know that I could use the @media command and assign a different css stylesheet if the browser is a certain size, but it would be great if I could make it fluid.

Before:

[image: Browser wide]

After:

[image: Browser narrow]

Thank you!

Comment: Yes there are many ways to do this. What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried using float, which doesn't seem to work as there are three divs rather than two (plus when there are two they don't drop down), tried using display:table-cell. Nothing seems to work, i'm probably being really rather dumb. clear: right seems to corrupt everything

Comment: Are you using widths as a percentage? Bootstrap has this built-in with the grid system. I would recommend column widths with media queries.

Comment: Each div is set to 300px, already figured percentages wouldn't work :)

Comment: put in the code you tried to write.

Comment: float is your friend for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the divs in a container element, like....

```
<div class="wrapper">
     <div id="elem1"></div>
     <div id="elem2"></div>
     <div id="elem3"></div>
</div>
```

Then make sure .wrapper has a set width, most likely a percentage. If it has a set width and the inline elements are all floated left, once there is no longer room within the .wrapper div, they'll shift to the next line.

Comment: Woohoo brill, thank you! Didn't float them all to the left, that's where I went wrong.

Comment: Anyway to centre the wrapper in the middle of the page (horizontally)? It seems to stick to the left even when using margin:auto and text-align:center

Comment: The parent element of the wrapper class needs to have the text-align: center in there and also a defined width. Then use margin: 0 auto; on the wrapper class

Comment: Currently, this is how my page is setup:

<div class="maincontainer" style="width:100%; height:auto; text-align:center">
<div class="wrapper" style="width:80%; margin: 0 auto; height:auto">
     <div id="elem1"></div>
     <div id="elem2"></div>
     <div id="elem3"></div>
</div>
</div>

I want the maincontainer div to span the entire width of the browser, so can't really set a fixed width.

Comment: Sorry, in the comment editor, I added new lines to make the layout easier, but seems to remove those when you submit it

Comment: Sorted it, using width:auto on the wrapped does it perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<div class='box'></div>
<div class='box'></div>
<div class='box'></div>
```

and:

```
.box { 
   background: #000;
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   float: left;
}
```

They should automatically drop when below 900px, see: http://jsfiddle.net/JQFH7/

Comment: Cheers, sorry didn't see this answer as I was testing the other answer, both work well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Elements into it

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
<div>
```

CSS

```
.inner
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: black;
}

div#wrapper
{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rx4hvn/n6J75/)