# How can I make div's(All the same div id) drop down to a new line and display vertically instead of horizontally

Tags: html, css

I am pretty new to CSS but I was designing this landing page for my website and I can not figure out how to make the div's drop to a new line when they get pushed together from the width of the page. I used all the same div class names to make it easier when styling so if I could retain that, that would be awesome. Any help is Greatly appreciated!

Comment: Question is not clear. but hope this will help you:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24941891/dropping-inline-divs-to-a-new-line

Comment: Your title says they all have the same id. Your statement says they all have the same class name. Which is it? Of course, it doesn't matter if you don't supply any markup at all and we'll just close this altogether.

Answer (score 0):

To have divs be pushed to a new line when the browser window is too small to fit them inline, you simply need to float the divs. Here is a simple example:

HTML:

```
<div class="red box"></div>
<div class="blue box"></div>
<div class="green box"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
}

.red {
  background: #f00;
}

.blue {
  background: #0f0;
}

.green {
  background: #00f;
}
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/majestic84/pen/zYxqPdb)

Comment: Thanks for the input but I have tried that. I think its something with a predefined display position of the divs

Comment: @AzonYankee If you don't mind posting what you have so far, we can try to help you find the specific problem :)

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's a wild guess at an off topic question (no code offered). Do not answer off topic questions. Vote to close them instead. [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: is there a way I can upload my css/html file for the project?